# Write and read operation via synchronous serial port (Arduino Uno + ADNS2610)

Tags: serial, c++

## 1.Preliminaries

I have optical sensor ADNS2610 (see datasheet [here](http://bdml.stanford.edu/twiki/pub/Rise/OpticalDisplacementSensor/ADNS2051.pdf)) which I plug in to Arduino Uno R3 board.

It is possible either to read from either to write to the sensor. Here is what datasheet says (p. 12):

> **Write Operation**
>
> Write operations, where data is going from the microcontroller to the
>   ADNS-2610, is always initiated by the microcontroller and consists of
>   two bytes. The first byte contains the address (seven bits) and has a
>   “1” as its MSB to indicate data direction. The second byte contains
>   the data. The transfer is synchronized by **SCK**. The microcontroller
>   changes **SDIO** on falling edges of **SCK**. The ADNS-2610 reads **SDIO** on rising edges of **SCK**.
>   [image]
>
> **Read Operation**
>
> A read operation, meaning data that is going from the ADNS-2610 to the
>   microcontroller, is always initiated by the microcontroller and
>   consists of two bytes. The first byte that contains the address is
>   written by the microcontroller and has a “0” as its MSB to indicate
>   data direction. The second byte contains the data and is driven by the
>   ADNS-2610. The transfer synchronized by **SCK**. **SDIO** is changed
>   on falling edges of **SCK** and read on every rising edge of **SCK**. The
>   microcontroller must go to a High-Z state after the last address data
>   bit. The ADNS-2610 will go to the High-Z state after the last data
>   bit. Another thing to note during a read operation;
>   **SCK** needs to be delayed after the last address data bit to ensure that the ADNS-2610 has at least 100 μs to prepare the requested data.
>   This is shown in the timing diagrams below (See Figures to 23).[image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

## 2 Arduino program

`WriteRegister` and `ReadRegister` functions are borrowed (though slightly modified) from [OptiMouse](https://github.com/zapmaker/OptiMouse) project by zapmaker.

### 2.1 SetAddress function

This function writes the first byte: data direction (MSB) and address of a register (seven bits) which user intents to read from or to write to.

```
void ADNS2610::SetAddress( uint8_t address, DataDirection direction ) const
{
    pinMode( sdioPin, OUTPUT );

    /*Specify data direction:
     *MSB = 0   ===>   read operation
     *MSB = 1   ===>   write operation*/
    switch( direction )
    {
        case( toSensor ) :
            address |= 0b10000000 ;
            break;
        case( fromSensor ) :
            address &= ~0b10000000 ;
            break;
    }

    for( uint8_t mask = 0b10000000; mask; mask >>= 1 )
    {
        digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );
        digitalWrite( sdioPin, address & mask );
        digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );
    }

    /*Wait for 100 microseconds between address write operation
    *and read data operation (see p.15 of the datasheet)*/
    delayMicroseconds( 100 );
}
```

### 2.2 ReadRegister function

```
uint8_t ADNS2610::ReadRegister( uint8_t address ) const
{
    SetAddress( address, fromSensor );

    uint8_t data = 0;

    /*Read data from a register*/
    pinMode( sdioPin, INPUT );
    for( int i = 7; i >= 0; i++ )
    {
        digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );
        digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );

        data |= ( digitalRead( sdioPin ) << i );
    }

    /*Wait for 0.25 microseconds between read and either
     *read or write operations (see p.15 of the datasheet)*/
    delayMicroseconds( 1 );

    return data;
}
```

### 2.3 WriteRegister function

```
void ADNS2610::WriteRegister( uint8_t address, uint8_t data ) const
{
    SetAddress( address, toSensor );

    /*Write data to a register*/
    for( uint8_t mask = 0b10000000; mask; mask >>= 1 )
    {
        digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );
        digitalWrite( sdioPin, data & mask );
        digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );
    }

    /*Wait for 100 microseconds between write and either 
    *read or write operations (see p.15 of the datasheet)*/
    delayMicroseconds( 100 );
}
```

## 3.Discussion

### 3.1 Write operation

According to the datasheet

> ... The microcontroller changes **SDIO** on falling edges of **SCK**. The ADNS-2610 reads **SDIO** on rising edges of **SCK**.

And this is how I understand the code (see sec. 2.1):

```
digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );//create a falling edge
digitalWrite( sdioPin, address & mask );//change SDIO on falling edge
digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );//create a rising edge (ADNS reads here)
```

Two questions here:

1. The first line in the above creates a falling edge only if the previous state of **SCK** was `HIGH`, doesn't it? So would it be better to have the following:

   ```
   digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH);
   digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );//create a falling edge
   digitalWrite( sdioPin, address & mask );//change SDIO on falling edge
   digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );//create a rising edge (ADNS reads here)
   ```
2. On figure 20 (see sec. 1, Write operation) you can see that it is required some minimal duration of the clock pulses (250 ns). Does the above code provide such a duration? I know that ATMega328p has frequency 16 MHz, so it seems that time between two operations could be less than 250 ns. Am I right?

### 3.2 Read operation

According to the datasheet

> **SDIO** is changed on falling edges of **SCK** and read on every rising edge of **SCK**. The microcontroller must go to a High-Z state after the last address data bit. The ADNS-2610 will go to the High-Z state after the last data bit

And this is how I understand the code (see sec. 2.2):

```
digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );//create a falling edge (SDIO changes here)
digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );//create a rising edge

data |= ( digitalRead( sdioPin ) << i );//read SDIO on rising edge
```

Three questions here:

1. The first line in the code above creates a falling edge only if the previous state of **SCK** was `HIGH`, doesn't it? Would it be better to have the following:

   ```
   digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH);
   digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );//create a falling edge (SDIO changes here)
   digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );//create a rising edge

   data |= ( digitalRead( sdioPin ) << i );//read SDIO on rising edge
   ```
2. On figure 23 (see sec. 1,Read operation) you can see that it is required some minimal duration of the clock pulses (250 ns). Does the above code provide such a duration?
3. How do I set the microcontroller into High-Z state after the last address data bit?

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**

> The first line in the code above creates a falling edge only if the
>   previous state of SCK was HIGH, doesn't it? Would it be better to have
>   the following:
>
> ```
> digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH);
> digitalWrite( sckPin, LOW );//create a falling edge (SDIO changes here)
> digitalWrite( sckPin, HIGH );//create a rising edge
>
> data |= ( digitalRead( sdioPin ) << i );//read SDIO on rising edge
> ```

If you start from Cycle one.. **Yes**. Looking at the read cycle waveform, SCLK should be high before initiating a read or write request and after completing the communication.

**Question 2**

> On figure 23 (see sec. 1,Read operation) you can see that it is
>   required some minimal duration of the clock pulses (250 ns). Does the
>   above code provide such a duration?

```
Here is the code for digital write function
void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t timer = digitalPinToTimer(pin);
    uint8_t bit = digitalPinToBitMask(pin);
    uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(pin);
    volatile uint8_t *out;

    if (port == NOT_A_PIN)
        return;

    // If the pin that support PWM output, we need to turn it off
    // before doing a digital write.
    if (timer != NOT_ON_TIMER)
        turnOffPWM(timer);

    out = portOutputRegister(port);

    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();

    if (val == LOW) {
        *out &= ~bit;
    }
    else {
        *out |= bit;
    }

    SREG = oldSREG;
}
```

**Please do not give any delay.** the above DigtalWrite function will take 1000's of ns of delay already. it is sufficient.

**Question 3:**

> How do I set the micro controller into High-Z state after the last
>   address data bit?

I would do the following. Configure the pin which you want to **set to high impedance** as **input pin**. You can always change it to output mode before you want to use it again.